# RDP not connecting in Amazon EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

I recently opened the Amazon account and got the instance running with windows. I asigned the IP, subnet, network interface and also updated the rule to allow RDP from all IPs, Generated the key pair. After doing all these I am still not able to connect to RDP and when tried to ping the elastic IP assigned it showed as 'Request timed out'. Followed the steps in the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/concepts.html) from amazon but still not able to connect.

Is there anything i left to do?

Comment: Have you enabled Internet for instances in a VPC subnet?

Comment: Follow this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) to enable Internet.

Comment: Check this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. I just recreated the instance and problem solved.

Update:

When recreating i just reffered 2 links:

1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html#create-a-vpc

2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html

Comment: Is there a reason for using the answer section for what is a basic comment. If it is the answer you could answer it (with a bit more detail) and accept it as the answer your self, etc...

Comment: I don't know the cause of the problem and didn't had time, since it is the blank one i just recreated it. (also updated my answer with the links)